# Excel Cell formatting issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsoft excel whenever i enter data "10E2" it transforms it to "1.00E+03" as it considers character E as exponent.
But i don't want excel to consider that as i need to display value "10E2" only.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of the box to Text. It is set to General by default.
Right click on the cell and click format.
From the list select Text